# Umbraco 7: custom dropdown dynamically populated from Items in a specific node

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco7

I have a "Language" document type, and under my site's Content I have a folder called "Languages" which contains all the languages we support.

I created a custom Data Type called "Languages Dropdown", and I want this dropdown to be populated from the instances of "Language" present at a specific path.

This is my default Sitecore thinking in action. Is such a thing even possible in Umbraco?

Comment: If your heart is set on drop down then that's fine but the easiest way to achieve what you want out of the box is with a standard Multi-Node-Tree-Picker.  you can set a start node for the picker which would be the parent node of the instances of language.  I find the picker interface intuitive and simple and would tend to use this instead of a dropdown anyway.

Comment: Is there any reason I cannot set a start node as the source for a dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly - first of all, take a look at nuPickers and see if that can do what you want - 99% of the time this sort of thing can be handled really easily with that package:

https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/nupickers

Documentation can be found here:

https://github.com/uComponents/nuPickers/wiki

Comment: Cheers, I will give it a shot.